How to get day's number, month's number and year from a specific date using month's French name?
I'm completely new to JS Date Object, and I need to get day's number, month's number and year from a specific date using month's French name.
I know how to do it using month's English name:
const dt = new Date("12 may 1996"),
  day = dt.getDate(),
  month = dt.getMonth(),
  year = dt.getFullYear();

How can I accomplish this using French language for the month (with no arrays or objects)? E.g.:
const dt = new Date("12 mai 1996");


Date does not support that IIRC, something like dayjs will work tho.

With such specific requirements (no arrays or objects), you are left with the legendary if-else or switch-case solutions.

"with no arrays or objects" I would say it's (almost) impossible. "I'm completely new to JS Date Object" As you already know, new Date creates an object.

I would like to know that "almost".

Using arrays just means your code is more maintainable than the inevitable if jan else if feb else if mar...   You probably mean some built-in method like the opposite of toLocaleDateString

With "no objects" I mean: obj months = {1: "janvier", 2: février, ...};

@fdomn-m Exactly.

See Date.parse() To paraphrase: A library can help if [other] formats are to be accommodated.

As per first comment:  Date does not support that.   Code it yourself (using an array...) or use a library (which will use an array...)

@Yogi There's always a reason... It could be French, or Spanish, or Italian...

(with no arrays or objects) -> you can't do this without objects, because everything in JS is based on Objects, like any function. Your simple code with dt = new Date("12 may 1996") itself use the Date Object.

@Mister Jojo As explained above, with "no objects" I mean: obj months = {1: "janvier", 2: février, ...};.

@AbsoluteBeginner FYI many of the questions asked here are clear XY Problems or simply badly asked. Not saying yours is, just stating a fact. So, in the comments, people will ask questions about why there is a restriction or what they are actually trying to achieve. In many cases, answers bear little resemblance to the question due to the question itself.  The comments above are trying to establish if that is the case here.  eg why is there this arbitrary restriction to half the solution? In this case it looks like you just handwaviumed a restriction. Which is ok if that's the case.

One idea is using the toLocaleDateString passing the locale your wanting to decode, this then can create an array you can lookup to get the month index.


function getMonths(locale) {
  let d = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
  const ret = [];
  for (let m = 0; m < 12;m ++) {
    d.setMonth(m);
    ret.push(d.toLocaleDateString(locale,{month: 'long'}));
  }
  return ret;
}


function decodeDayMonthYear(datestr, locale) {
  const months = getMonths(locale);
  const sections = datestr.split(' ');
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(sections[0]);
  d.setMonth(months.indexOf(sections[1]));
  d.setYear(sections[2]);
  return d;
}

const dt = decodeDayMonthYear('12 mai 1996', 'fr-FR');
console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString());
const dt2 = decodeDayMonthYear('25 décembre 2024', 'fr-FR');
console.log(dt2.toLocaleDateString());




Your approach is quite similar to mine. This is what I guessed: const months = []; for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) months.push(getMonthName(i)); const getMonthName = m => new Date(2023, m, 0).toLocaleString("fr-FR", {month: "long"}); const getMonthNumber = m => months.indexOf(m) + 1;. But I would like to avoid that array and use a built-in method - if there's one.
